# Need Select top 10 people SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need SQL query for MySQL to select top 10 people with most followers

**my table**

```
id | user_id | follow_id
1     3          6
2     3          7
3     4          6
4     5          6
5     7          3
6     9          7
```

From example user with id 6 have 3 time followed , 7->2 and 3->1, so TOP 10 will be

user with id 6,7,3 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use MySQL [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) aggregation funciton

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(follow_id) AS total_followers
FROM users 
GROUP BY follow_id 
ORDER BY total_followers LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Take care using work like `count` since it may be part of [MySQL Reserved Word](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11578960/292015). `COUNT` is not, I know, but you are facing a beginner :) At list, encapsulate `count` with `\``.

Comment: Why did you use `SELECT *`? What do you the `id` and `user_id` columns will show? Which one of the followers?

Comment: This should be `SELECT follow_id, ...` and not `SELECT user_id, ...`. It's a query that produces wrong results this way, as it is now.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT `follow_id`, COUNT(1) AS `followers`
FROM  `tbl`
GROUP BY `follow_id`
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: -1 The first column of the resultset is `one-of` the counted values it has no meaning, same for group by. You perhaps wanted to use `user_id` instead.

Comment: Counting on `*` is bad practice. Prefer the [Kasia Gogolek proposal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11578960/292015).

Comment: @MihaiStancu No, the group by needs to be `follow_id` and not `user_id`. And, the OP wants a list of the followed users.

Comment: @Adrien: Using `COUNT(*)` in MySQL is no bad practise at all. In fact, in many versions, it's more efficient than `COUNT(column)`.

Comment: The difference is:

- `COUNT(*)` will count the number of records.  
- `COUNT(column_name)` will count the number of records where column_name is not null.

If you're using MyISAM and there is no `WHERE` clause, then the optimiser doesn't even have to look at the table, since the number of rows is already cached.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd You were right, i had misinterpreted the requirement.

Comment: @Adrien: I know the difference. What is your point? This is not a MyISAM table (as far as we know), it has a `GROUP BY` so that doesn't apply and in this case  `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(follow_id)` are equivalent in result - but sometimes not in efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT follow_id,count(id) AS cnt FROM table 
GROUP BY follow_id ORDER BY cnt DESC  LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT user_id , COUNT(id) AS count FROM tbl GROUP BY follow_id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: @MihaiStancu: I have Corrected it

Answer (score 2):

You need to group the results by the follow_id and then count how many results are in this group and sort this by the number of results per group in a descending order and then define you want to limit it to only 10 results which can be done by using LIMIT 0,10

The following query works perfectly in MySQL 5

```
SELECT follow_id, COUNT(follow_id) AS nr
FROM test.testtable
GROUP BY follow_id
ORDER BY nr DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
select follow_id
from myTable
group by follow_id
order by count(user_id)
Limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    follow_id,
          COUNT(user_id) AS number_of_followers
    FROM  table
    GROUP BY follow_id
    ORDER BY number_of_followers DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Nope you're counting how many people each user follows - not how many are following them.

Comment: this will count the count of people who followed someone

Comment: You're right, misread the requirement. It's been inversed now.